# Backbone this.model.models undefined error

Tags: backbone.js

I´m trying to fetch a mongodb collection from my server (node.js) and using backbone render this content on a template (underscore). Mongodb and node.js part works fine cause i proved to do a console.log with the collection and it brings me the collection. I have the code below (I cutted some parts of code that are irrelevant):

***router.js***

```
appRouter.on('route:books', function () {
    var bookList = new BookCollection();
    bookList.fetch({
        success: function () {
            $('#content').html(new BookListView( { model: bookList } ).el);
        }
    });
});
```

***bookListView.js***

```
  , render: function ()  {
        var books = this.model.models;

        $(this.el).html(this.template());

        _.each(this.model.models, function(book) {
            $('.thumbnails', this.el).append(new BookListItemView( { model: book } ).render().el);
        }, this);
  }
```

***bookListItemView.js***

```
  , render: function ()  {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
  }
```

My problem is that **this.model.models = *undefined*** and i don´t understand why cause **5 minutes before the same code works perfectly**. If I do console.log(this.model) it brings me the list of models.

My code is inspired on that repo https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar from Christophe Coenraets

Hope your help, thak you, regards

Comment: `console.log(this.model)` in `bookListView.js` should give you an instance of a `BookCollection`, could you please verify that ? And try to see what all changes you did in last 5 mins which are breaking the existing functionality :-/

Comment: It doesn't look like you are calling render on BookListView in router.js, are you?

Comment: Check that `this.model` is actually an instance of Backbone Collection and not just an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might because of you are calling the `render` method in some other place.

The collection is only populated after the fetch which is `Async` . So when the `render` method is called the `model` attribute is undefined. So you will see an error.

To fix this you have to call  `render` only after the collection is populated and the view initialized.( In the success callback )

```
bookList.fetch({
        success: function () {
            var bookListView = new BookListView( { model: bookList } );
            $('#content').html(bookListView.el);
            bookListView.render(); // Need to call render here
        }
    });
```

Also why do you want too name in model which inturn is actually a collection.

`( { collection: bookList })` makes more sense than `( { model: bookList } )`